getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Couldn't establish the client connection while connecting hive db in Node.js
I've been facing issue while connecting hive db in Node.js code even though I've formed proper hostname as connection string.
Below is the syntax of hostname which I've connected in the code.
jdbc: hive2://hostname:port/schema_name
I've gone through various resources in Stack Overflow but I couldn't find proper solution to solve this
How to connect hive server using node js
I've been trying to connect hive db using below Node.js code and attached the error as well.
const hive = require('hive-driver');
const { TCLIService, TCLIService_types } = hive.thrift;
const client = new hive.HiveClient(
    TCLIService,
    TCLIService_types
);
const utils = new hive.HiveUtils(
    TCLIService_types
);
 
client.connect(
    {
        host: 'jdbc:hive2://host:port/schemaname',
        port: 10000
    },
    new hive.connections.TcpConnection(),
    new hive.auth.PlainTcpAuthentication({
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    })
).then(async client => {
    const session = await client.openSession({
        client_protocol: TCLIService_types.TProtocolVersion.HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V10
    });
    const operation = await session.executeStatement(
        'SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 10'
    );
    await utils.waitUntilReady(operation, false, () => {});
    await utils.fetchAll(operation);

    console.log(
        utils.getResult(selectDataOperation).getValue()
    );

    await operation.close();
    await session.close();
});

And the error:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',


Don't use runnable snippets for code that isn't browser HTML, CSS, and JS. The snippet interface should have tipped you off about this already.

And of course: did you search for Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND and at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] already? Because there are a lot of posts about those on SO already so did none of those posts have answers that applied to your situation? And if so: remember to talk about that in your post.

Hi Mike, Yes I've not used the same code. In my scenario I've to connect to hive db from nodejs. I couldn't establish the client connection. Could you please check Is the hostname format is right to connect db from nodejs.

Your host address starts with two protocols. So that's not a legal address.
